# VirtualBox Host-Only adapters and bridged network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

After 3 hours of wasted time trying to figure out what and why, I decided to come here for help. Problem appeared after upgrade to Windows 10 Creators Update.

So, before I upgraded to Windows 10 Creators Update, in Network Adapters I had one active adapter **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"** which I was using for one of my VM. After upgraded to Creators Update that adapter was gone. After that I just updated VirtualBox to version 5.1.20.
 

But now I'm experiencing weird problem. When I create new Host-Only adapter, it's named **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"**. When I create second one, it's named **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3"**. What I can't figure out is why first new adapter is named with number **"#2"** at end. No matter where I'm creating this new adapter - using VirtualBox or adding new Network Adapter manually at Device Manager, first adapter always has number **"#2"** at end of name. Also I can't rename connection name, it returns error that **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" already exists**.
Links to pictures - [1](http://lejup.lv/f/5902ff2128a2avpewitf1493368609.JPG), [2](http://lejup.lv/f/5902ff2128a2aswodbnd1493368609.JPG), [3](http://lejup.lv/f/5902ff2128a2axndfuay1493368609.png).

But that's not why I'm here. I'm here because I can't use VirtualBox. This is what I see when I'm choosing which adapter I want to use - [4](http://lejup.lv/f/5903005345242ocxcipn1493368915.png). There is no adapter with number **"#2"** and even no adapter with number **"#3"** when I have two Host-Only active adapters. When I'm trying to start VM with **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"** selected, it returns this - [5](http://lejup.lv/f/590301c708c50fwogwpm1493369287.JPG).

I have tried to uninstall VirtualBox completely, removing all VirtualBox drivers using [this tutorial](https://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/). After uninstall I have tried to search for this missing adapter at registry, but I can't find it anywhere. I have removed every registry entry related to **"VirtualBox", "VBox"**. I have tried to search for **"Host-Only", "Ethernet", "Adapter"**, but I can't find this missing adapter. Also I deleted all folders and files related to VirtualBox on C: drive. But after I installed VirtualBox version 5.1.21, it again create **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"** as first adapter and it still shows **"VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"** on available bridged network adapters.

I really need help, because I can't use my VM correctly right now. Thanks!

Comment: I've also been running into this on multiple machines. On some of them both the unnumbered and `#2` adapters are unavailable. I've gone all the way up to `#4` being the first adapter created.

Comment: This is also not specific to the Creator's Update, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on screenshot #4, you should choose "Host-only Network" rather than "Bridged Network". It should work... you just need to live with an increasing number at the adapter name each time you upgrade virtualbox, :).

The root cause is that VB didn't remove the previous host-only adapter correctly at update, so each time a ghost connection is left in the windows system. Interestingly, VB treated them as bridged network adapters -- which is deadly wrong. You can identify these ghost connections by

```
VBoxManage list -l bridgedifs
```

Based on the GUIDs, you can manually remove these keys from registry, then reinstall virtualbox.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Uninstall VirtualBox first. Next, Shift+Restart your computer into command prompt mode. In command prompt mode, type regedit. Highlight the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then Load Hive (File -> Load Hive). Open the file

> C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM

and load it with any temporary name you want. (Here remember to load the SYSTEM file located in **C: drive** because the default folder in command prompt mode is X: drive). Then, you may just find

```
ControlSet001
```

key under the hive you have loaded. Locate

```
Control\NetworkSetup2\Interfaces
```

and find the profile of that '#2 adapter' and delete it. After that, close the regedit and type 'exit' on command prompt. Go back to Windows and reinstall VirtualBox.